# Finding anagrams contained in a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, anagram

I'm trying to write a program which accepts a string and groups anagrams
of the string together in list of lists, sorted lexicographically.

For example, the following string:

```
eat tea tan ate nat bat
```

Should produce the following output(order of the lines is important):

```
ate eat tea
bat
nat tan
```

The program I have written:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_anagrams(source):
d = defaultdict(list)
for word in source:
    key = "".join(sorted(word))
    d[key].append(word)
return d

def print_anagrams(my_string):
word_source = my_string.split(" ")
d = get_anagrams(word_source)
for key, anagrams in d.items():
    print(" ".join(sorted(anagrams)))

print_anagrams("eat tea tan ate nat bat")
```

This program produces the correct anagrams, but each time I run the program the order of the lines compared to the expected output change.

So sometimes I get

```
nat tan
ate eat tea
bat
```

And other times I do get the correct output

```
ate eat tea
bat
nat tan
```

Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't deface your own question once it has attracted answers, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of dictionary keys is random by design.

If you want to print anagrams in order of their occurrence in original text, use `OrderedDict` which stores keys in the same order as you inserted them:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_anagrams(source):
    d = OrderedDict()
    for word in source:
        key = "".join(sorted(word))
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = []
        d[key].append(word)
    return d

def print_anagrams(my_string):
    word_source = my_string.split(" ")
    d = get_anagrams(word_source)
    for key, anagrams in d.items():
        print(" ".join(sorted(anagrams)))

print_anagrams("eat tea tan ate nat bat")
```

Output:

```
ate eat tea
nat tan
bat
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) there, and if you iterate over it with `for key, anagrams in d.items():` you get no guarantee regarding ordering:

> The `keys()` method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the
>   keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it
>   sorted, just apply the `sorted()` function to it). To check whether a
>   single key is in the dictionary, use the in keyword.

You would thus edit your code like this, to *iterate over the sorted dictionary* (sorted *by key*):

```
for key, anagrams in sorted(d.items()):
    print(" ".join(sorted(anagrams)))
```

This guarantees that the output is always

```
bat
ate eat tea
nat tan
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the correct output has first line: ate eat tea and so on. Your suggestion still doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: If anagrams must be printed in the order of their occurrence in original text, use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @Landon: Then fix your program accordingly, now that you know what's going on :)

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13: I assume this is homework, and as such `OrderedDict` *could* be considered cheating by the teacher (then again, while we are talking anagrams, `cheater` is an anagram of `teacher` :P)

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 can you provide an example of how to use ordered dict,  not too sure how to use it.

Comment: @Landon: I wouldn't bother. Fix your program using the regular data structures. I suggest you work on it a bit, now that you know the tricky part about dictionaries, and maybe open another question later when you stumble into another problem, so that we can focus on that :) Be warned that if your question morphs into "do my homework for me" it may get closed.

Comment: @Landon: you know, there is a beautiful and simple solution that *doesn't need dictionaries at all*, just lists. We have determined that you do not want to access your anagrams based on a *specific* key, you want to print ordered lists of anagrams, in turn lexicographically ordered.